# Why do the colors of my .ply model look pale after converting it to the .fbx format?

Tags: unity, fbx

I have a colorful .ply file that I'm trying to use in Unity.

I have seen a few .ply to .fbx converters online, but they all make the model lose a lot of its color.

This is how the .ply file looks in MeshLab:
[image]

And this is how the .fbx file looks after using some convertor:

[image]

How can I convert the .ply file to Unity without losing a lot of its color?

Comment: Welcome to the Game Dev Stack Exchange. Images can be added by using the image button in the toolbar above the post editor; the image button is between the `{ }` button & the `<>` button. Linking to off site images tends to result in dead links over time. You can read more about adding images & other formatting [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: The way the colors are displayed is probably more dependent on the rendering engine and shader than on the model. I suspect that the second render uses a shader with specular highlights, while the first does not. Those highlights add some white to the image, which makes the whole image look less saturated. How it looks in your game will also depend on the shaders and material settings you use for the model. You might want to import the model into Unity and play around with the sliders on the material(s) of the model.